# missing packages in mobaxterm apt-get session

Tags: python, apt-get

When attempting to install Python in MobaXterm, two packages are not found in the local repository. I have found at least one of them in an external repository and I would like to configure my terminal to use another repository beside the one indicated in the example directory tree as follows:

```
http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/release/cygwin-devel
```

Either that or I would like to change the package version to one that exists in this location, but then I worry about package versioning issues.

Or a third option would be to download the packages I find in the other locations and install them using the same terminal I used to install the other Python packages.

Here are the two packages with issues:

```
Installing cygwin-devel
Downloading cygwin-devel-2.7.0-1.tar.xz...
Downloading /home/mobaxterm/.aptcyg/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.kernel.org%2fsourceware%2fcygwin/release/cygwin-devel/cygwin-devel-2.7.0-1.tar.xz using Windows internet settings
sha512sum: can't open 'cygwin-devel-2.7.0-1.tar.xz': No such file or directory
/bin/apt-cyg: line 476: test: 8f382e85417a4efa951607776be66cf91381e4075bcc4458da40141951305675faff4890bd2723de91483725c5d5bd726128355a2de41a0c743428b2829fe48c: unary operator expected
md5sum: can't open 'cygwin-devel-2.7.0-1.tar.xz': No such file or directory
/bin/apt-cyg: line 479: test: 8f382e85417a4efa951607776be66cf91381e4075bcc4458da40141951305675faff4890bd2723de91483725c5d5bd726128355a2de41a0c743428b2829fe48c: unary operator expected
Checksum did not match, exiting

Installing libexpat1
Downloading libexpat1-2.2.0-0.tar.xz...
Downloading /home/mobaxterm/.aptcyg/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.kernel.org%2fsourceware%2fcygwin/release/libexpat1/libexpat1-2.2.0-0.tar.xz using Windows internet settings
sha512sum: can't open 'libexpat1-2.2.0-0.tar.xz': No such file or directory
/bin/apt-cyg: line 476: test: a39f95f129fc7abe1e22f71925844dac0160f7c536f01bb8e5cc1f9b23f19266dd95e633a4e44d6b4ad792aa25c2a69b473dd06400ef4e7dab02e88877020455: unary operator expected
md5sum: can't open 'libexpat1-2.2.0-0.tar.xz': No such file or directory
/bin/apt-cyg: line 479: test: a39f95f129fc7abe1e22f71925844dac0160f7c536f01bb8e5cc1f9b23f19266dd95e633a4e44d6b4ad792aa25c2a69b473dd06400ef4e7dab02e88877020455: unary operator expected
Checksum did not match, exiting
```

Thanks in advance for any insights that might lead me to resolve this and have a clean Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround - hopefully. In essence, the setup.ini file on the repository references a version of the packages that actually does not exist on that repository. After reading up on apt-get I learned that I could pass a legacy flag to get an earlier version of the package installed:

```
[micro.MSI] ➤ apt-get install --legacy libexpat1
Found package libexpat1

Installing libexpat1
Downloading libexpat1-2.2.0-0.tar.xz...
Unpacking libexpat1-2.2.0-0.tar.xz...
Extracting dependencies for usr/bin/cygexpat-1.dll...
Package libexpat1 requires the following packages, installing cygwin
Package cygwin is already installed, skipping
Package libexpat1 installed.

Rebasing new libraries
```

This might introduce versioning issues, but the dependency was already there, as it should be since it was installed in the earlier python installation. Now I can see if I can get the other modules installed for my project.

If anyone else has advice about this package management issue, please chime in. I am wondering if I should notify the source repository owners about their setup.ini file pointing to versions that do not exist.